# Does setting Application.ScreenUpdating to False applies to every workbook that has subsequently been opened within a subroutine?

Tags: excel, vba

> OS: Windows 10 Pro Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1052)
> Application: Microsoft 365 Excel Version 2106 (Build 14131.20278)
> VBA: Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1 Version 1110

---

The module that contains the code resides in a Macro-enabled workbook, which opens other workbooks in a folder and modify each if it passes certain criteria. The workbook itself that contains the code is not being altered, it just holds the code.

I'm wondering if I need to turn Application.ScreenUpdating off and on for every subsequent workbook that will be opened within a subroutine, such as in this one:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Code()

'Variable declaration
Dim fsoLib As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim strSrcPath As String
Dim fsoFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
Dim fsoFiles As Scripting.Files
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbs As Excel.Workbooks

'Assign values to variables
Set fsoLib = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
strSrcPath = "/SourcePath"
Set fsoFolder = fsoLib.GetFolder(strSrcPath)
Set fsoFiles = fsoFolder.Files
Set wbs = Excel.Workbooks

'Modify workbooks
For Each fsoFile In fsoFiles
    Set wb = wbs.Open(fsoFile)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'TURNS OFF SCREEN UPDATING
        'Code to modify workbooks here..
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'TURNS SCREEN UPDATING BACK ON

    wb.Close(True)
Next

'Housekeeping
Set fsoLib = Nothing
strSrcPath = vbEmpty
Set fsoFolder = Nothing
Set fsoFile = Nothing
Set fsoFiles = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set wbs = Nothing

'Success indicator
Debug.Print "You have reached the end of the line.."

End Sub
```

..or do I just place it on top and bottom, respectively? Like in this one:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Code()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Rest of the code here..

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I couldn't find any resources about it on the internet that's current. I found one old discussion [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/screen-updating-between-workbooks.86905/) but the OP had mixed results depending on whether it is run from the VBA IDE or otherwise.

I'd appreciate any help from you guys. Thank you all very much.

Comment: It's `Application.ScreenUpdating`, not `SomeWorkbook.ScreenUpdating`, hence the scope.

Comment: So, it applies to all workbooks including workbooks that's being opened at a later time? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: It only applies while the code is running - it's not a "sticky" setting.

Comment: @TimWilliams, what I would like to know is if I have to turn it off and on for every subsequent workbook that is going to be opened at a later time within the subroutine. From my understanding on what the first commenter has said, ScreenUpdating is under Application object, which is the very top in the hierarchy of VBA object model, so the scope of it includes all other workbooks within the subroutine. But an OP from another website, which I also included the link on my post, had a different experience.

Comment: To check it you can put `Debug.Pring Application.ScreenUpdating` after `Set wb = wbs.Open(fsoFile)` statement

Comment: @АлексейР, and to all who gave their valuable comments, thank you very much. It is now clear to me, it printed `False` to the immediate window..